# How to get the specific <K,V> entry based on the given key in Java HashMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Ex. I have the following `HashMap`, and how to get the entry `'b'=6` if I know the key `'b'`. Is there any way to do it?

```
Map<Character, Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
map.put('a',7);
map.put('b',6);
map.put('c',5);`
```

By the way, I want to do this is because all those entries are in a priority queue. I have to remove that entry from the priority queue and re-insert it to make sure it is in order.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. Why is a simple `get()` call not adequate? E.g. `Character key = 'b'; Integer value = map.get(key);`

Comment: Why do you store k+v in the priority queue? Better to store key only.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the key, simply get the value using [`Map#get(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)). As long as you know both, you have the *entry*. The `Map` interface doesn't provide a specific method that returns a certain entry.

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = ...
Character key = 'b';
Integer value = map.get(key);

// now with the 'key' and 'value' that make TOGETHER an entry.
```

If you really somehow need an `Entry<Character, Integer>` construct it like this:

```
Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry = new SimpleEntry<>(key, value);
```

There is no better way. One would say you can use Stream API to iterate through the entries and return the first one found, however, you lose the main benefit of the `HashMap` which is the constant-time look-up.

```
// DON'T DO THIS!

Entry<Character, Integer> entry = map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> key.equals(e.getKey()))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
public Entry<Character, Integer> entry_return(Map<Character, Integer> map) {
    for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getKey() == 'b')
            return entry;
    }
}
```

or use a stream API if you really need the entry but i don't know if that is very common/usefull

Comment: It's important to point out that the main benefit of HashMap is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 9, you can use static method [`Map.entry​(K k, V v)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)), which:

> returns an unmodifiable `Map.Entry` containing the given key and value.

So, you can obtain your `Entry<K, V>` instance, as:

```java
Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry = Map.entry(key, map.get(key));
```

where `map` stores a reference to your `Map<K, V>` instance.